# how to change the path of stylesheets that skeleton automatically load

Tags: javascript, css, spring-mvc, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I use a Responsive UI boilerplate skeleton. And I also use springmvc. So I need to map the static resources to a directory so that they can be loaded correctly.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

in my jsp file

```
<head>
        <title>Plain Art | 艺术品定制</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,900,300italic" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.min.js"/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.dropotron.js"/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/config.js"/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url  value="/resources/js/skel.min.js"/>" ></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/skel-panels.min.js'/>" ></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/skel-noscript.css'/>" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/style.css'/>" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/style-desktop.css'/>" />
        </noscript>

        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/html5shiv.js'/>"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/ie8.css'/>" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
```

and when I start the server and load the page, the `<head>` is rendered as below

[image]

I want to change the path of stylesheets but I couldn't find which blocks of code in skel.min.js controlls loading `style-desktop.css` or `style-mobile.css`.

I manually change the source in browser inspector

```
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style-desktop.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

into

```
<link href="/Project/resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Project/resources/css/style-desktop.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and the stylesheets can be correctly loaded. But it responsively change the .css file. When I switch to mobile size, it will automatically load style-mobile.css, and this will also cause a problem.

My question is :
1) how can I change the wrong path and make it compatible with spring mvc?
2) is there an another way of referencing static resources? Instead of using tag

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the mapping to the following?

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/Project/resources/" />
```